# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el valor de una variable a una función para poder crear un registro en la tabla pivote?

Tags: laravel-8

Quiero matricular a un estudiante en un curso creando un registro en la tabla pivote ya que tienen una relación de muchos a muchos (**nxn**) pero no logro pasar `student_id` a la función `enrolled`
Código:

```
 i<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use App\Models\Student;
use App\Models\Course;

use Livewire\Component;


class EnrollStudent extends Component
{
    public $open = false;
    Public $student_id;
    Public $course;
    

    
 
    public function render()
    {
        $courses=Course::all();
        $students=Student::all();

        return view('livewire.enroll-student',compact('students','courses'));
    }
    
    public function enrolled(Course $course){
       
        
       $course->students()->attach($this->student_id);
       
       
       
         
      }

}
```

Comment: Listo ahí explique un poco mas gracias